# Which form of adjective should be used when we compare two qualities of single noun or pronoun?

Tags: adjectives

For example,

> She is wiser than intelligent.

Or

> She is more wise than intelligent.

Although the second sounds good to me, I want to know whether there is any rule for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the second version sounds better, and I would not see anything wrong with it.

The first sounds odd because a person is being compared directly to a adjective,

> She is wiser than intelligent

whereas we usually compare two or more things, or  people.

> She is wiser than most people    (comparing people)
>   The owl is said to be wiser than the fox (comparing animals)
>   It is wiser to check shipping costs than presume you are saving money. (comparing costs)

Online, there are several question about *He is more wise(r) than brave* but I'm not sure about the grammatical explanations offered.

> 45. When two qualities of the same person or thing are compared, the Comparative in-er is not used. 'More' is used for this purpose.
>       Incorrect- He is wiser than brave.
>       Correct- He is more wise than brave
>       (Source: [SSC Exam Preparation](https://www.facebook.com/573154216122888/posts/correction-of-sentences-in-english-language26-a-past-tense-in-main-clause-may-be/582259081879068/))

Elsewhere… ([Campusgate](https://www.campusgate.co.in/) )

[image]

Which looks reasonable unless you missed their earlier example, which is clearly wrong!

[image]

Hunting in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is%20more%20wise%20than%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMjrrX75rkAhXN3KQKHRE2CDkQ_AUIFygB&biw=1309&bih=692), the following examples caught my attention

- *It is a most agreeable and fascinating cullibility, whereof it is **more wise than foolish** to become the willing and unresisting dupe.*
- *No nation is **more wise than the English** in managing their own market.*
- *This territory is apportioned, in separate Governments, to the different sons of the Ameer, a policy which is **more wise than popular***.
- *it is a veil over his wisdom; remove his eloquence, reduce his language, withdraw his images, and you will find that he is **more wise than eloquent***.

I don't know if the examination prep website or my explanation above helps explain why writing "more wise" is preferable or acceptable but safe to say it is grammatical, despite *wise* being monosyllabic.